# Getting java.lang.Exception: Method xxx should have no parameters with jmockit:1.20, junit:4.12 with JDK11

Tags: junit4, jmockit, java-11

I am using jmockit:1.20, junit:4.12 with JDK11. Earlier it was workign with Java 8 but now its not.

The test class is:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import mockit.Deencapsulation;
import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.StrictExpectations;
import mockit.Tested;
import mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit;

@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class FlywayHelperTest
{
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Method XXX_catch_throw_UpgradeException should have no parameters
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:155)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateTestMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:208)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:188)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit.<init>(JMockit.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

I have tried 2 options but still not solved: 
1. Jmockit dependency before junit.
2. Added below filter in build.gradle

```
 test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    filter {
        exclude '**/module-info.class'
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade jmockit to a version that works with JDK 11?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed out by Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493518/getting-java-lang-exception-method-xxx-should-have-no-parameters-with-jmockit1#comment93868199_53493518), you can upgrade your `jmockit` version to the [latest release](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jmockit/jmockit/1.44/jar)

```
compile 'org.jmockit:jmockit:1.44'
```

To be precise `jmockit` became compatible with JDK9 and modules with [release version 1.23](http://jmockit.github.io/changes.html#1.23).

Comment: My current version of jmockit is 1.20, so upgrading to 1.44 would lead to many changes.